# How to find the same touch coordinate of same view of different size ios objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My query is that I want to get the same touch coordinates of same view in different size. For example: If I have an image view of size 500x500 and another view in next VC of size 200x200. In the first view (i.e, 500x500) I have given tap gesture and i have plotted the coordinate. When I click next button it would go to another VC having the image view of size 200x200. I have to get the same point from where I have touch on the much larger image. I have used CGPoint for plotting it was fine when done with same size image view but problem started when the size of the image view changed. Can anyone help me out please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When tapped on image, you can calculate the tapped point related to image size.

```
actualImageWidth = 500
actualImageHeight = 500

tappedX = 100
tappedY = 100
```

If your image size is 200 * 200, then your formula to be,

```
newImageWidth = 200
newImageHeight = 200

xPosition = tappedX / (acuatlImageWidth / newImageWidth)
yPosition = tappedY / (acuatlImageHeight / newImageHeight)
```

If your image size is 1000 * 100, then your formula to be,

```
newImageWidth = 1000
newImageHeight = 1000

xPosition = tappedX * (acuatlImageWidth / newImageWidth)
yPosition = tappedY * (acuatlImageHeight / newImageHeight)
```